# How to manage common code with node.js - For a react-native perspective

Tags: node.js, npm, react-native

Earlier I believed that one of the aims of `react-native` was to be able to re-use a lot of the code across multiple platforms. The more I read, it seems to not be the case (or one of the primary cases). What I want to achieve is a project structure like:

```
project
    +- app
      +- components
    +- android
    +- ios
    +- web
```

Where `app/components` contain most of the common code that we write, which can be re-used by android/ios (from react-native) and `web` is a Spring boot project which can use stuff from `app/components` as well with react-native-web to package a JS that can be hosted on the web.

Let's say I want to create a layout that I would like to use everywhere:

```
import {View, Text} from 'react-native'

class MyView extends Component {
    render() {
        return (
            <View><Text>Welcome!</Text></View>
        );
    }
}
```

I am assuming that `react-native` will be loaded as required from the `node_modules` in the specific projects (`react-native-web` for `web` and `react-native` for `ios/android`).

Now, how do I import this created view in all three of the projects? I am not sure if this is the best project structure there is. What would be the right way to do this? Should `app` have it's own `package.json`? Even if it does, I don't believe `npm` supports sub-projects as well as `gradle` does (I know, apples to oranges comparison, but I don't think a build-system like gulp/webpack also does, please correct me if I'm wrong).

**EDIT**

So I experimented with this a bit. The problem is that I cannot have the following structure:

```
project
    app
    android
    ios
    web
       package.json
    package.json
```

If there are any packages common in `web/package.json` and `package.json` I am getting a `Duplicate module name: AutoFocusUtils`, from probably `node-haste` (which appears to be some dep management system built at facebook).

Also, for some reason, when building `web` from webpack somehow requires me to have the `babel-preset-*` and `react-native` dependencies in the context of `app`, which is still fine, I guess I can work that out later.

So I moved it around a bit:

```
project
    app
        package.json
    native
        android
        ios
        index.android.js
        index.ios.js
        package.json
    web
        package.json
```

Everything was fine, but from `index.android.js`, I can no longer do this:

```
import MyView from './../app/myview'
```

I get an error on the phone saying `Requiring unknown module ./../app/myview`. However, it works just fine from `web` (while building with webpack). My `webpack.config` in case it helps: http://pastebin.com/RzmWDgFe

**EDIT**

I finally reached a code structure that we are happy with. In case anyone comes here looking for a working solution: http://git.nomadly.in/rohan/react-native-tri-platform-starter

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are right; code reuse is a major selling point. As you probably know the react native packager uses the `.ios.js` or `.android.js` File ending to determine which version to load. So IMHO the best way to structure your code is to have a structure like you suggested with `web`, `android`, `ios` only including the specific files for the platforms (HTML, Xcode project, etc.) and all react components in the app/components directory. For best reuse you should write your top level components (and all other that are possible) to be independent from the system and include minimal components (e.g. Headline, FullscreenImage, etc.) which then are platform dependent.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I have been trying to experiment with this a bit, would you mind taking a look at my EDIT and seeing if I can re-structure this out?

Comment: the structure looks okay, you have a .. too much in the import Statement